# script to add values from another sheet to monthly calendar sheet - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

I have 4 names in column like this:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I want to add them into this Dynamic Monthly Calendar Template: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RZ9RXTg44XkBBZx98eKeGWajYVgrULaz64Ws7FpaPGI/edit?usp=sharing

Each day has atleast 1 name and every 2 days has 2 different names (no duplicate). Expected result like this: [image: expected result]

*(update)* My problem:

> - This is a Dynamic Calendar, which update date cells by the month. How can I set values to only the date cells in month (ignore the blue
>     cells)?
> - How can I set 4 values into, example, 30 days order like 1-A, 2-B, 3-C, 4-A, 5-B?

Comment: Sounds interesting. And what exactly is your programming problem?

Comment: my problem is i don't know what to do. I only know a very basic use of google app script.

Comment: I know how to set values for data range in GAS. But this template is a dynamic calendar. Date cells can change when the month changed, but values must be only set in range of the dates (1 to 28/29/30/31) (ignore the blue cells)

Comment: Do you want to insert into each odd day a random value from your names, and for every even day a random combination of two names? And thereby, the combination for even days shall be different each time?

Comment: @ziganotschka kinda like that. First, I want to insert to all days of the month the random order of 4 names, like ABCDABCD... or BCADBCAD... (only first 4 days is random order, then everday after follow that first 4 days). Second, every even day must add a name which must be different from the first one and also has the same rule of order like above

Comment: I find out that if the second name order (the even dates) have 2 names in reverse, there're unlikely any chance of duplicate. Example: first order (all dates): ABCDABCD...
second order (even dates): AB**DC**AB**DC**...

Comment: @LêThànhVinh As one with knowledge of  “a very basic use of google app script”, you have chosen a project that is _extremely_ complex and complicated. Your question also  lacks detail about the circumstances of what/why you are trying to achieve. May I respectfully suggest that you may need to break your task into more manageable chunks, and focus on developing your skills on the more basic aspects of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your updated questions:

**1. How to assign values only to cells that contain a valid date**

- You can write a script that checks the cell contents of the range of interest for numbers (=dates), and inserts values into the cells underneath the numbers:
  `if(typeof contents[i][j]=="number")`

**2. How to populate the calendar with values A, B, C, D sequentially**

- You can assign your values of interest to an array and loop through the array starting after the 4end of the loop from 0 by using the modulus:
  `k=(k+1)%4;`

> Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var myValues=["A", "B", "C", "D"];
  var k=0;
  var myValue="";
  var myRange=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("January 2019").getRange("A3:G16");
  var contents=myRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<contents.length;i++){
    for (var j=0; j<contents[0].length;j++){
      if(typeof contents[i][j]=="number"){
        Logger.log(contents[i][j] + " is a number");
        myValue=myValues[k];
        myRange.getCell(i+2,j+1).setValue(myValue);
        k=(k+1)%4;
      }
    }
  }
}
```